# floating point subtraction for binary numbers

Tags: arithmetic, binary, floating-point

Consider that I want to do a binary operation on the following floating point numbers:  `0.35-0.62`

I can reach the end but I can not figure out how the sign bit is determined.

**1)** first we write the numbers in binary. Assume that we can represent 4 digits in the fraction part

```
0.35 -> 0.010110...   -> 1.0110 * 2^(-2)
0.62 -> 0.1001111.... -> 1.0011 * 2^(-1)
```

**2)** We have to modify the smaller exponent to make it equal to the larger one. So:

```
1.0011 * 2^(-1)   =   0.1011 * 2^(-1)
```

**3)** Subtract the mantises:

```
    0.1011
    1.0011-
 ----------
{1} 1.1000
```

`{1}` means there is a carry bit. The new mantis in `1.1000`. So how we determine the sign bit? We can do that operation using 2's complement like this:

```
       0.1011
       0.1101 +
  ------------
  {0}  1.1000
```

The carry bit is zero. So is that a positive number or negative one? How the sign is determined?

**4)** Assuming that we know the sign is negative! the result is `1.1000 * 2^(-1)`.

Any idea on determining the sign bit?

Comment: That $\{1\}$ is the sign bit, isn't it?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to represent sign bit in the floating point representation! That is the carry based on my calculations

Comment: I'm saying that that is how the sign bit is determined -- it's just the carry bit.